# XmlDocument query taking two values

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, xmldocument

How I can make following query

If I have `XmlDocument`  and it may have following xml

```
<EquipmentParameterModified dateTime="2011-04-06T12:03:10.00+01:00" parameter="ExtApp">
  <Extensions ParameterId="External App Interface" FromParameterValue="" ToParameterValue="DISABLED"/>
</EquipmentParameterModified>
```

How I can check that I have `EquipmentParameterModified` and take values of `ParameterId` and `ToParameterValue`

Thanks for help.

Comment: how do you mean 'check if you have'? .. does the Xml sometimes contain these nodes and sometimes not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(new StringReader(xmlstr));
XmlNode node = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Extensions").Item(0);
string id =  node.Attributes["ParameterId"].Value;
string val = node.Attributes["ToParameterValue"].Value;
```

Comment: plus: You should check whether you actually found any "Extensions" tags (XmlNodeList.Count property), or use a try-catch block.

Comment: @Efrain Just for simplicity. It gives an idea about how to do.

Comment: @L.B,  I am getting on xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Extensions")[0]; Array accessor prefix must be an array type

Comment: @NightWalker See the edited version. I changed `[0]` to `Item(0)`

Comment: @L.B I got one more error now on Attributes line "accessor must be ordinal but was 'String'"

Comment: @NightWalker I works for me(targeting 2.0 framework) but you can also try `foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes) { string s = attr.Name + "=" + attr.Value; }`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find the element given the 2 input search values?  What do you want your output to be?  If you just want to see that you have a matching element, this code should do the trick:

If yes, try something like this:

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            var paramId = "External App Interface";
            var toParameterValue = "DISABLED";

            var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"
<EquipmentParameterModified dateTime='2011-04-06T12:03:10.00+01:00' parameter='ExtApp'>
  <Extensions ParameterId='External App Interface' FromParameterValue='' ToParameterValue='DISABLED'/>
</EquipmentParameterModified>");

            var ret = xdoc.Root
                .Elements("Extensions")
                .Where(e => e.Attribute("ParameterId").Value == paramId &&
                            e.Attribute("ToParameterValue").Value == toParameterValue)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (ret != null)
                Console.WriteLine(ret.Name);

        }
```

**Update for .NET 2.0 & XmlDocument:**

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            var paramId = "External App Interface";
            var toParameterValue = "DISABLED";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(@"
<EquipmentParameterModified dateTime='2011-04-06T12:03:10.00+01:00' parameter='ExtApp'>
  <Extensions ParameterId='External App Interface' FromParameterValue='' ToParameterValue='DISABLED'/>
</EquipmentParameterModified>");

            XmlNode node = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Extensions")[0];
            if (node.Attributes["ParameterId"].Value == paramId &&
                node.Attributes["ToParameterValue"].Value == toParameterValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found matching node:" + node.Name);
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Isn't XDocument just .NET 3.5 and higher?  In any case, I updated the question tags

Comment: @ JohnD , Sorry my mistake  , I was thinking about XmlDocument and wrote XDocument

Comment: Array accessor prefix must be an array type. i got it on xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName

Comment: That is strange, it is an XmlNodeList which should have an indexer property.  Can you see what the return value of xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Extensions") is?

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working, but can you try .Item(0) instead of [0]? (code updated)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using XPath to get the element you're aiming for, do a null check, then get specific attributes of that element, doing a null check on the attribute value before calling the `.Value` property.